# Object gets created with null variables

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I ran into an error, bug or just weird behaviour while going through some java tutorial exercises. I have a Person object being initialized, the arguments I pass go through an overloaded constructor and the object gets created, but it returns with null variables. I'll show the relevant portion of the program:

```
public class Person {
    private double weight;
    private String name;
    private Date birthday;

    public Person(double weight, String name, int day, int month, int year){
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.birthday = new Date(year,month,day);
        //System.out.println("this is a constructor call");
    }

    public Person(String name,int day, int month, int year){
        new Person(0,name,0,day,month,year);
        //System.out.println("this is a constructor call");
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "My name is " + this.name + ", my weight is " + this.weight + ", my birthday is "
                + this.birthday;
    }
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person pekka = new Person("Pekka", 15, 2, 1993);
        Person steve = new Person("Thomas", 1, 3, 1955);

        System.out.println(pekka);
        System.out.println(steve);
```

This will return "My name is null, my weight is 0.0, my birthday is null". The solution is to use this(0,name,0,day,month,year) instead of new Person in the constructor, but I don't understand why. Debugging with breakpoints show the arguments going through both constructors, but then it turns to null back in main.

Comment: To call a constructor from another constructor, use `this(...)`

Comment: Unrelated, yet important: you shouldn't use a `Date`, as that is an obsolete class. It was replaced by classes from the `java.time` package. In your case, you may want to store a birthday in a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `new Person(0, name, day, month, year)`<sup>1</sup>, you are creating a *new* (!) object, which is then immediately discarded. The fields of the current object are left unchanged, meaning they will keep their default values.

`this()` is the structure within the Java language to call a different-argument constructor to defer the construction of the current object being constructed.

```java
// Constructor A
Person(String name) {
    this(name, 50.0); // ---------------------+   this...
}                     //                      |
                      //                      |
// Constructor B                              |
Person(String name, double weight) { //   <---+   ...points to this constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.weigth = weigth;
}
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I assumed you made a typo, because no six-argument constructor exists, and the compiler would not allow you to compile it.</sup>

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, however I was not aware a six-argument constructor wasn't allowed. It seems to compile for me?

Comment: I don't believe `new Person(0,name,0,day,month,year)` will ever compile when you have no 6-argument constructor. Unless someone have been tinkering with your compiler.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your second constructor you create a new *local* instance of a `Person` and don't initialise any of your fields.

What you actually need to do is to call through the first constructor with `this`:

```
public Person(String name,int day, int month, int year){
    this(0,name,day,month,year);
    //---------^----- 0 removed from here
}
```

Notice that I've removed the third parameter here, because your constructor doesn't take 6 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. What you do, can be rewritten as:

```
public Person(String name,int day, int month, int year){
        Person p = new Person(0,name,0,day,month,year);
        //System.out.println("this is a constructor call");
    }
```

That p is a local variable that doesn't exist outside of the scope of the original constructor.

What you are looking for, is:

```
public Person(String name,int day, int month, int year){
        this(0,name,0,day,month,year);
        //System.out.println("this is a constructor call");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Withing second constructor, You are passing a redundant argument to the first one. (the  0  after the name)

plus you should change the second constructor from

```
new Person(0,name,0,day,month,year);
```

to

```
this(0,name,day,month,year);
```

Comment: Ah, my bad here. I was editing the code for this answer and I forgot to remove that (I added another variable later). My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Your constructor:

```
public Person(String name,int day, int month, int year){
    new Person(0,name,0,day,month,year); // this creates another instance of Person, but doesn't modify existing one
    //System.out.println("this is a constructor call");
}
```

`new Person(...)` creates new instance of `Person` class and returns it's reference. It does not affect current instance. If You want to call constructor inside another constructor use `this` keyword:

```
public Person(String name,int day, int month, int year){
    this(0,name,day,month,year); // this creates another instance of Person, but doesn't modify existing one
    //System.out.println("this is a constructor call");
}
```